# PowerBuilder compatibility in Windows environment

Tags: sybase, powerbuilder

I am using PowerGen Professional Version 8.0.0.15 for PowerBuilderV12.0 in Windows2003 (32 bit-4GB RAM) os. Now due to insufficient memory and build is taking 3 hours time so I need to move the setup to higher configuration machine for example 8GB to 16GB RAM.

For this i need 64 bit Windows OS. Does this improve the build timing or how I could imporve or reduce the build timings?

Till date we are compiling in 32 bit OS will it affect the .exe if i compile it in 64 bit machine? Will there any backward compatability for PowerGen to compile to 32bit from 64 bit machine?

Answer (score 0):

A 32bit app can run on 64bit Windows without issue. They are limited to about 3.5GB of memory though. The main advantage with a 64bit Windows is that each 32bit app can use the maximum amount without having to compete with the OS and other programs running.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, I've never seen additional system memory improve the performance of PowerBuilder build processes. When I've observed the processes, they were largely disk I/O bound. I've benchmarked benefits of using a RAM disk, to the point that they outweighed the cost of copying PBLs to and from RAM disk exclusively for that one build. (And, no, I haven't found Windows using system memory as disk cache to be close to the same benefit.) My current favorite RAM disk is from DataRam. I haven't tried any benchmarking with SSDs.

You might also want to make sure that you're making best advantage of incremental builds. I used to have pretty bad experience with incremental builds, but find them much better after PB11.

Good luck,

Terty